# Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtCallExpression

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

Decompiler tool of my IDE is not working.

Here is my code which I want to decompile:

```
data class FetchOrdersState(
    val orders: List<Order> = listOf(),
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val error: String = ""
) : OrderState {
    companion object {
        val Empty = FetchOrdersState()
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting in the IDE when I visit `Tools` > `Kotlin` > `Show Kotlin Bytecode`

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: 
Failed to generate expression: KtCallExpression
File being compiled: (20,31) in /Users/.../src/commonMain/kotlin/.../OrderState.kt
The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.getPackageMemberContainingClassesInfo(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:356)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:314)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:430)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultParameterValueLoader.lambda$static$0(DefaultParameterValueLoader.java:30)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.lambda$generateDefaultImplBody$5(FunctionCodegen.java:1278)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.runWithShouldMarkLineNumbers(ExpressionCodegen.java:1559)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateDefaultImplBody(FunctionCodegen.java:1274)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateDefaultIfNeeded(FunctionCodegen.java:1203)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ConstructorCodegen.generatePrimaryConstructor(ConstructorCodegen.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ImplementationBodyCodegen.generateConstructors(ImplementationBodyCodegen.java:457)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:132)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:305)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:289)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:138)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:77)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:62)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.KotlinCompilerIde.compile(KotlinCompilerIde.kt:144)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$Companion.compileSingleFile(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:272)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$Companion.getBytecodeForFile(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$UpdateBytecodeToolWindowTask.processRequest(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:111)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.internal.KotlinBytecodeToolWindow$UpdateBytecodeToolWindowTask.processRequest(KotlinBytecodeToolWindow.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask$1$1.run(LongRunningReadTask.java:115)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:866)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask.lambda$runWithWriteActionPriority$0(LongRunningReadTask.java:235)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask.runWithWriteActionPriority(LongRunningReadTask.java:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.LongRunningReadTask$1.run(LongRunningReadTask.java:110)
at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:276)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No implClassName for @kotlin.internal.InlineOnly public inline fun <T> listOf(): kotlin.collections.List<T> defined in kotlin.collections[DeserializedSimpleFunctionDescriptor@43dad151]
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.getPackageMemberContainingClassesInfo(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.getPackageMemberOwnerInternalName(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1369)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.internalNameForPackageMemberOwner(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1315)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.access$internalNameForPackageMemberOwner(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1283)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapOwner(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:163)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapOwner(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:142)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapToCallableMethod(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:544)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.resolveToCallable(ExpressionCodegen.java:2727)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeFunction(ExpressionCodegen.java:2602)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeFunction(ExpressionCodegen.java:2576)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:2470)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCallExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:125)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:332)
... 45 more
```

> This works absolutely fine if I comment out the listOf() line from my data class.

Comment: Submitted bug request to Kotlin team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19289 Feel free to vote and follow

Comment: Can you attach the code of `Order` and `OrderState `? What version of the Kotlin plugin and Android Studio do you use?